# attempting to get data from indexed table produces -java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.query.internal.ParameterMetadataImpl

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-search, nomethoderror

I am attempting to retrieve data from hibernate search, after indexing the table and I attempt to make a search I get this error even when everything looks perfect to me. I have googled and found this solution
[How to fix "NoSuchMethodError ParameterMetadataImpl <init>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53905421/how-to-fix-nosuchmethoderror-parametermetadataimpl-init) but still did not provide a headway to solving the problem-
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.query.internal.ParameterMetadataImpl.([Lorg/hibernate/engine/query/spi/OrdinalParameterDescriptor;Ljava/util/Map;)V

here is my complete pom.xml file

```
        <!--<dependency>-->
           <!--<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>-->
           <!--<artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>-->
           <!--<version>5.6.0.Final</version>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                <optional>true</optional>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
                <version>5.8.2.Final</version>
            </dependency>
        
        


</project>
```

kindly assist

Comment: unrelated, but you have several pdfbox versions, and all of these are outdated. The current one is 2.0.21 or 1.8.16. You can use jempbox (which doesn't exist in 2.0) with pdfbox 2 if you need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version of Hibernate Search you're using is simply too old, and not compatible with the version of Hibernate ORM provided by Spring Boot.

You should check the [compatibility matrix on the Hibernate website](https://hibernate.org/search/releases/#compatibility-matrix) and pick the Hibernate Search version accordingly.

Spring Boot 2.1.4.RELEASE [uses Hibernate ORM 5.3.9.Final](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.4.RELEASE/reference/html/appendix-dependency-versions.html). According to the compatibility matrix, with Hibernate ORM 5.3.x, you should use Hibernate Search 5.10.x. As indicated [here](https://hibernate.org/search/releases/5.10/#releases), the latest release in the 5.10 series is currently `5.10.9.Final`.

So, change this:

```xml
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
                <version>5.8.2.Final</version>
            </dependency>
```

To this:

```xml
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
                <version>5.10.9.Final</version>
            </dependency>
```